# center formsite form

Tags: javascript, html

Setting up a quick form using an embedded template but I want to center the form and cannot.

```
<a name="form789985197" id="formAnchor789985197"></a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://fs8.formsite.com/include/form/embedManager.js?789985197"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
EmbedManager.embed({
    key: "http://fs8.formsite.com/res/showFormEmbed?EParam=bJeI6E3QIKDSIfZNMjkSkRGOwQgdGLHi&789985197",
    width: "70%"
});
</script>
<!-- Notes: 
To control the width of the form, change width: "100%" to any number or percentage.
To pre-populate fields in the form or to use a custom resize callback, see http://fs8.formsite.com/documentation/embedded-form.html
-->
```

How can I center the form?

Here is the code pad [link](http://codepad.org/A3EsMv1g).

Comment: can't you contain it in a div, and center the div using `margin: auto;` or `text-align: center`?

Comment: it is impossible to give css suggestions for unknown html and css

Comment: share your css with us then only we can identify the exact issue...

Comment: @charlietfl    I do not have the css or html it is the code is embedded.  Basically, the code is auto generated from the form template page.  Thanks.

Comment: the point is...it is incumbent on you to present the data so we can see it...  a demo would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used Embedded Form, but I read the [documentation](http://fs8.formsite.com/documentation/embedded-form.html) and set up this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/roimergarcia/NxzCH/ . It looks like the `a` tag is just a marker and a `iframe` is inserted just before it. The solution is to warp your `a` tag inside a div, and set `text-align:center` to that div:

```
<div id="formContainer" style='text-align: center;'>
    <a name="form789985197" id="formAnchor789985197"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://fs8.formsite.com/include/form/embedManager.js?789985197"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
EmbedManager.embed({
    key: "http://fs8.formsite.com/res/showFormEmbed?EParam=bJeI6E3QIKDSIfZNMjkSkRGOwQgdGLHi&789985197",
    width: "70%"
});
</script>
```